# Tenor guitar tunings: which is higher pitched?

Tags: guitar, alternative-tunings

I have read of three common tenor guitar tunings:

1. "standard" CGDA
2. "Irish" GDAE
3. "Chicago" DGBE

"Chicago" tuning is just like the top four strings of a regular 6-string guitar.

My question is about "standard" vs "Irish" tunings - which is tuned to a higher pitch?

And extending the question a bit... how do the highest and lowest pitches of "standard" and "Irish" compare to "Chicago"?

CGDA is the same notes as a Mandolin - is it down an octave? Is the C a whole step below the D of "Chicago" (4th string of regular guitar) and the A on top pitched higher than top E of regular guitar?

Would that make "Irish" the lower pitched tuning, with the bottom G matching 3rd fret of low E string on regular guitar, and top E matching top E?

Comment: Ah, I see from @Aaron's answer that I got mandolin tuning wrong... it's actually "Irish" tenor that is like a mandolin, just down an octave. But yes, "Standard" is higher pitched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0. Standard 6-string tuning = E2–A2–**D3–G3–B3–E4**
1. "Standard" tuning = C3−G3−D4−A4
2. "Irish violin" tuning = G2−D3−A3−E4
3. "Chicago" tuning = D3−G3−B3−E4
4. Mandolin tuning = G3–D4–A4–E5

Thus, the lowest string of "Irish" is tuned a fourth lower than in "Standard", and "Chicago" is one step higher.

Sources:

- Tenor guitar: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenor_guitar#Tuning)
- 6-String guitar: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guitar_tunings#Standard)
- Mandolin: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandolin#Tuning)